# HTML5 Boilerplate makes a gap in the bottom of the site

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate

I'm starting with HTML5 Boilerplate this days and, in my actual project, I'm having some trouble.
As I see, the CSS of Boilerplate defines the `<html>` with this:

```
html {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

This makes a gap in the bottom of the site and, by removing font-size and line-height, the gap decreases but doesn't disappear.

This gap only appears on Chrome and not in Firefox, Safari or Opera.

Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: try setting (min-) `height to 100%`

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: could you replicate it in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it guys.

It was something with cache and javascript.

I've cleaned the browser cache and hit Ctrl+F5. It seems to be ok now.

Thank you.